# Generate 3 distinct random integers via a uniformly distributed RNG

Tags: algorithm, random

Suppose I have a `randint(A, B)` function which generates a uniformly distributed random integer in the (inclusive) range `[A, B]`. For example, `1 <= randint(1, 10) <= 10`. How can I efficiently randomly generate 3 distinct integers within a certain range?

**This should be done with exactly 3 calls to `randint(A, B)`**. I don't care which permutation of the three numbers I get; it can be random or have a defined order.

I'm not just trying to find any algorithm to do this, but (within reason) the fastest ones which use the least additional memory.

```py
def rand3(low, high):
    assert high - low + 1 >= 3
    # Magic!
    return n1, n2, n3 # each number has low <= n <= high, each number is distinct
```

---

The easiest way to do this, albeit very expensive, is to generate a list of numbers `[low, low + 1, ..., high]`, then do the Fisher-Yates shuffle to select 3 elements. It's not necessary to fully evaluate Fischer-Yates, as we can just roll three indices. However, I definitely do not want to create this array in memory.

---

For 2 integers, it suffices to roll the second integer in the range less one, adjusting its value upward if it's greater than or equal to the first number:

```py
def rand2(low, high):
    i1 = randint(low, high)
    i2 = randint(low, high - 1)
    n1 = i1
    n2 = i2 + (i2 >= n1)
    return n1, n2
```

However, it's not straightforward to extend this to three integers. I believe it should be possible to do something like this:

```py
# I _think_ this works?
def rand3(low, high):
    i1 = randint(low, high)
    i2 = randint(low, high - 1)
    i3 = randint(low, high - 2)

    n1 = i1
    n2 = i2 + (i2 >= n1)
    if n1 > n2: n1, n2 = n2, n1
    n3 = i3 + (i3 >= n1)
    n3 = n3 + (n3 >= n2)

    return n1, n2, n3
```

However, I feel like there has to be something simpler than this. Is the 3 element problem really that much more complex that we need to sort the 2 integers and that the second conditional (`n3 >= n2`) must depend on an intermediate value of `n3`? I was expecting something much closer to the 2 element problem.

Comment: Also known as "Sample 3 random integers from an interval without replacement"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if these variations make you happier, but this `rand3` has one fewer comparison at least.

The idea is to simulate a couple steps of Fisher--Yates. In `rand3`, we work backward from the index `i3` to find the value. The first `if` undoes the second swap, and the second `if` undoes the first swap.

```
import collections
from random import randint


def rand2(low, high):
    i1 = randint(low, high)
    i2 = randint(low, high - 1)
    if i2 == i1:
        i2 = high
    return i1, i2


def rand3(low, high):
    i1 = randint(low, high)
    i2 = randint(low, high - 1)
    i3 = randint(low, high - 2)
    if i3 == i2:
        i3 = high - 1
    if i3 == i1:
        i3 = high
    if i2 == i1:
        i2 = high
    return i1, i2, i3


print(collections.Counter(rand3(1, 4) for i in range(1000000)))
```

Comment: From the last idea I had in the question, although I would like something better than it, the issue is that I don't even know if it works. I _think_ it works, but I don't really know. So it's not that I'm trying to find a variation that "makes me happy" but that I'm trying to find one that works with O(1) space and 3 calls to `randint`. So yes, your solution does indeed work for what I'm trying to find

Comment: @Justin ok, fixed. The idea is simulate three steps of Fisher--Yates.

Comment: That makes sense. I actually tried to model my idea off of Fisher-Yates as well, but I think it's much easier to reason through your algorithm here.

Comment: I did some simple benchmarks, and this version is the fastest out of what I tested. The C++ compiler optimizes the branches into conditional moves. I don't think it matters much to try to get an improvement on top of this, as the `randint(...)` is realistically what this function is spending all of its time doing. Even with a very fast random number generator of subpar random quality (optimizing just for speed), the calls to `randint()` were taking more than 5/6 the time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, though probably not most performant way is to just keep rechoosing the random numbers when they don't meet the criteria.  Checking for duplicates is trivial, just make a `set` and the duplicates will be thrown out.

```
def rand3(low, high):
    assert high - low + 1 >= 3
    s = set()
    while len(s) != 3:
        s = set([randint(low, high), randint(low, high), randint(low, high)])
    return tuple(set)
```

Comment: I definitely do not want to do this. I want to do this with exactly three calls to `randint`. The code in the question, while it is python, is not intended to say that I want this algorithm done in Python, but to show an example of what it is that I want. I'm trying to find a good algorithm for any programming language