# Sample 3 integers without replacement in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I want to sample three integers among `{0, 1, ..., n-1}` without replacement.

Here is how I proceed so far:

```cpp
#include <random>

/* constructs vector {0, 1, ..., n-1} --------------------------------------- */
template <class T>
std::vector<T> integers_n(T n) {
  std::vector<T> out(n);
  for(T i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    out[i] = i;
  }
  return out;
}

/* samples three integers among {0, 1, ..., n-1} ---------------------------- */
const std::vector<int> choose3(const int n,
                               std::default_random_engine& generator) {
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> sampler1(0, n - 1);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> sampler2(0, n - 2);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> sampler3(0, n - 3);
  const int i1 = sampler1(generator);
  const int i2 = sampler2(generator);
  const int i3 = sampler3(generator);
  std::vector<int> elems = integers_n(n);
  elems.erase(elems.begin() + i1);
  const int j2 = elems[i2];
  elems.erase(elems.begin() + i2);
  const int j3 = elems[i3];
  return {i1, j2, j3};
}
```

This works but is there a better way?

I want to perform this sampling multiple times, in a loop. Is it time-consuming to redefine the samplers for each iteration?

For technical reasons, I am restricted to C++ 11.

Comment: I know you're restricted to C++11, but when you get to upgrade to C++17, see the second answer on the target.

Comment: Who closed this question? The linked question has no appropriate answer to my question. `shuffle` shuffles the entire range! Please reopen.

Comment: You can always ping the closer of the question with @. I don't follow. Apart from the fact that you want to sample 3 values, and the target wants to sample 4, why do you think it's not a dupe exactly?

Comment: The marked duplicate shuffles the entire range the pulls the first N values from it (like shuffling a deck of cards, then taking the top N). It will be computationally more expensive than my proposed answer when you only need a small number of values.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The fact that there might be better answers to the target, doesn't mean this is not a duplicate. You could post your answer there if it's better than the other solutions. As far as I can tell, both questions are asking the same thing.

Comment: @cigien I didn't say it wasn't a duplicate. Since the OP was indirectly asking about performance, I felt an explanation was warranted. There is a comment to the accepted answer of the dup that discusses the time spent by the shuffle.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Ok, the `sample` solution in the target is the most efficient solution, but it does require C++17, which the OP can't use. If you feel the constraint on C++11 makes this not an exact duplicate, you should vote to reopen. I think that's reasonable enough.

Comment: @cigien On SO it is not possible to mark as duplicate a question if the target has no accepted answer. Here it has an accepted answer, but this one does not answer my question.

Comment: Again, can you explain why the target is not a duplicate of your question?

Comment: @cigien Again, it *is* a duplicate, but *it has no appropriate answer*.

Comment: That's not relevant to the duplicate closure. If an appropriate answer *could* be posted on the target, then it's a duplicate. You could try to add a bounty to the target question, that way it will get more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sample without replacement from `0, ..., n - 1` without allocating any additional memory; `elem` is unneeded. The key is to *simulate* a few steps of the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), as seen in [David Eisenstat's answer to my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64359519/1896169).

```
// std::array<int, 3> requires no heap allocation, so is a better choice.
std::array<int, 3> choose3(const int n,
                           std::default_random_engine& generator) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> sampler1(0, n - 1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> sampler2(0, n - 2);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> sampler3(0, n - 3);
    // Algorithm translated from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64359519/1896169
    int i1 = sampler1(generator);
    int i2 = sampler2(generator);
    int i3 = sampler3(generator);

    if (i3 == i2) i3 = n - 2;
    if (i3 == i1) i3 = n - 1;
    if (i2 == i1) i2 = n - 1;
    return {i1, i2, i3};
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it clear this is a *uniform* sampling? (I did some simulations and it seems to be uniform indeed).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent It is just as uniform as the other solutions. The 3 `i` values come from uniform distributions. Two of those values may be changed if they would result in duplicate numbers, but the effect of that change is the same as replacing elements in `elem` as I do in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @1201ProgramAlarm. Please, is it correct to do `if(i2 == i1) { i2 = i1 == n - 2 ? n - 1 : n - 2; }` for the case of two integers only?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent No, for two integers only the `i2 == i1` case is unchanged. The `i2`/`i1` check has no dependency on how may other values may be chosen later. You could just as easily check `i2 == i1` right after assigning to `i2`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Sorry I don't understand :(. Could you show me the code please? Do you mean one has to keep the third `if` only?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Exactly. If you only want 2 integers, keeping just the last of the three ifs should work. See also the other question I linked; David Eisenstat has psuedocode for the 2-case, which is just the third `if` here. Alternatively, in that question, I show that the 2-case can be the two numbers `i1` and `i1 + (i2 >= i1)`. I do not know which is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `erase`, you can replace the element chosen from the vector by the last element.

```
elems[i1] = elems[n - 1];
```

Then do the same for the second:

```
elems[i2] = elems[n - 2];
```

The time to construct the three `uniform_int_distribution` is minimal. Constructing `elems` will consume more time.

Comment: You can view this as a partial Fisher-Yates Shuffle where you only select 3 elements.